# pgn viewer support on mobile phones

Tags: discussion, support, pgn-viewer

Might be a dupe, the PGN viewer doesn't support Mobile phones, I tried Dolphin version 11.2.8 browser on Android version 4.1.2 samsung s3 mini and I also tried using  the SE android app, it shows the FEN not the diagram, why? and can it  be fixed? since most of us rely too much on phones thee days.

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. The lack of PGN rendering in the SE android app [has been raised already on meta](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/358/167), but the similar issue concerning your browser seems not to have been. It might be useful to include your Dolphin and android version information too.

Comment: @ETD just did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a partial fix: you can click on **full site** at the bottom of the screen and the board does render fine.